# Bootstrap grid system on Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with column size on Microsoft Edge and IE11. Everything works fine on other browsers, but on Edge and IE, it seems like the column width are larger than they are supposed to be. For example, an inline form group looks normal on Chrome:

[image: chrome inline form-group]

And this is the result on Edge:

[image: Edge inline form-group]

Code:

```
<div class="well">
    <h5>Address</h5>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="company-address" class="col-xs-4 control-label label-left">Company name</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" id="company" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Everywhere where I use `col-*-*` classes, the width seem to be larger than the bootstrap proportion. Thus many of them ends up stacking vertically as they don't fit on the same `row`

Also another bizarre difference is the `form-control`'s height seemingly bigger on Edge.

What may cause such behavior and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure your browser isn't set with a zoom?

Comment: Working fine in my IE11/Edge ...and compared with Chrome/Firefox, they all looks pretty much the same

Comment: @Gofilord Zoom level is at 100%

Comment: @LGSon frustrating. I removed all styles that may override bootstrap (I usually just override background colors and such), still a disaster. Took screenshots with dev tool open on both browser: [Chrome & Edge grid problem](http://imgur.com/a/GtCoj)

Comment: Can imagine, and can't help as I don't have the issue

Comment: Facing the same issue. It gets resolved if you zoom in/out or force re-render the element. I think the issue is with edge miscalculating width due to some reason.